# CQRS - Map Commands from dynamic object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, azure-functions, automapper, cqrs

I am using CQRS design pattern with Azure Functions. I am getting dynamic request object through my HttpTrigger Azure Function. Now I have map my commands based on the "EventType" property in the request.

Here is my Azure Function.

```
[FunctionName("ReceiveEvent")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("ReceiveEvent HTTP trigger function started processing request.");

             log.LogInformation($"Pushing Events to Azure Blob on storage account :-{CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureWebJobsStorage")}");

            IActionResult actionResult = null;

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            var eventType = EventType.Unknown;

            string eventTypeValue = data.EventType;
            Enum.TryParse(eventTypeValue, true, out eventType);



            switch (eventType)
            {
                case EventType.CARD_BLOCK:
                    command = _cardBlockCommandMapper.Map(data);
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_CANCEL:
                    command = _cardCancelCommandMapper.Map(data);
                    break;


            }

            return actionResult;
```

Here is my command mapper :

```
public class CardBlockCommandMapper : ICardBlockCommandMapper
    {
        public CardBlockCommand Map(dynamic data)
        {
            return new CardBlockCommand
            {
                Message = data.Message,
                ModifiedByName = data.ModifiedByName
            };
        }
    }
```

Commands:

```
public abstract class Command
    {
        public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    }

public class CardBlockCommand : Command
    {
        public override EventType EventType => EventType.CARD_BLOCK;
        public string ModifiedByName { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
 public class CardCancelledCommand:Command
    {
        public override EventType EventType => EventType.CARD_CANCEL;
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<string> MetaData { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Command handler:

```
public class CardBlockCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CardBlockCommand>
    {
        private readonly IAzureBlobStorage _azureBlobStorage;

        public CardBlockCommandHandler(IAzureBlobStorage azureBlobStorage)
        {
            _azureBlobStorage = azureBlobStorage;
        }

        public void Handle(CardBlockCommand command)
        {
            try
            {
                //TODO: Store into blob
                //_azureBlobStorage.UploadMessageContentAsync(storageConnectionString: string.Empty,
                //    storageContainerName: string.Empty, blobName: string.Empty, content: string.Empty);

                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

My question is here, I have total 15 different types of event type. Do I need to create a separate command mapper for each type? Or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, how about making your commandmapper generic? and can I assume that your commands contain different properties?

Comment: Yes my command contain different properties based on the event type

Comment: so the point is to just map that dynamic data to some concrete class, basing on the EventType?

Comment: @kebek yes this is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: ok, one last questions: those modes share some common interface or base class? Could you share your `CardBlockCommand` and `CardCancelCommand` classes, it would be easier to fully understand ;p

Comment: My idea would be to deserialize a json string to a concrete object after you figured out the event type, that way you can move away from the dynamic object.

Comment: With the assumption that properties from the dynamic always match to properties on those classes, that would be the easiest solution, but it might not be the case :P

Comment: @kebek I have added my commands.

Comment: and what do you need the `command` for? In your code you didn't declare it and I don't also see the usage of this variable

Comment: @kebek I have also added my command handler which will receive the command

Comment: @kebek viewing those commands deserializing after you figured out the event type seems an easy and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jochem Van Hespen mentioned simplest way would be to deserialize that json to a concrete type basing on the Enum value.

Analyze this code, and see if it's a better solution for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestAPI
{
    public abstract class Command
    {
        public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }
    }

    public class CardBlockCommand : Command
    {
        public override EventType EventType => EventType.CARD_BLOCK;
        public string ModifiedByName { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    public class CardCancelledCommand : Command
    {
        public override EventType EventType => EventType.CARD_CANCEL;
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<string> MetaData { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EventType
    {
        CARD_BLOCK,
        CARD_CANCEL,
        Unknown
    }


    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var requestBody =
                @"{ eventType: ""CARD_BLOCK"", message: ""message"", modifiedByName: ""ModifiedByName""}";  // sample response (json) from request
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            string eventTypeValue = data.EventType;
            Enum.TryParse(eventTypeValue, true, out EventType eventType);



            switch (eventType)
            {
                case EventType.CARD_BLOCK:
                    CardBlockCommand cardBlockCommand = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardBlockCommand>(requestBody);
                    // handler.Handle(cardBlockCommand)
                    break;
                case EventType.CARD_CANCEL:
                    CardCancelledCommand cardCancelledCommand = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CardCancelledCommand>(requestBody);
                    // handler.Handle(cardCancelledCommand)
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```